# Hiding shortcode buttons from wysiwyg editor in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am developing a wordpress plugin, where i have multiple wysiwyg editors using wp_editor() for generating templates and shortcode buttons in the editor. what I want is, hide these shortcode buttons from page and post editors and only show in my custom visual editors is this possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

Comment: Show how you're encoding the shortcode buttons.